# simple gravatar not displaying in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, gravatar

I took reference from this site:
http://tomatohater.com/2008/08/16/implementing-gravatar-django/

I have profile app that has templatetags directory with a mytags.py in it.

Contents of mytags.py

```
import urllib, hashlib
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('templatetags/gravatar.html')
def show_gravatar(email, size=48):
    default = "http://www.mysite.com/media/images/no-avatar.gif"

    url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?"
    url += urllib.urlencode({
        'gravatar_id': hashlib.md5(email).hexdigest(),
        'default': default,
        'size': str(size)
    })
    return {'gravatar': {'url': url, 'size': size}}
```

Contents of templates/templatetags/gravatar.html

```
<img src="{{ gravatar.url }}" width="{{ gravatar.size }}" height="{{ gravatar.size }}" border="0" />
```

The tag is utilized in profile.html template file.

But the gravatar is not displayed in profile.html. However the source shows

```
<div class="gravatar">
<a href="">
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?default=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Fmedia%2Fimages%2Fno-avatar.gif&amp;size=48&amp;gravatar_id=5d1b0b64499475516bd9c051aa7f3560" width="48" height="48" border="0" />
</a></div>
```

Comment: tried it with https://github.com/nvie/django-gravatar but it loads fallback image and not a real gravatar.

Comment: finally got it working with github.com/nvie/django-gravatar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="{{ gravatar.url|safe }}" width="{{ gravatar.size }}" height="{{ gravatar.size }}" border="0" />
```

`Safe` template filter prevents auto-escaping `&amp;`

Comment: I tested you code and was redirected to `default` url that is 404. It's ok because I have no avatar

Answer (score 0):

When I try the image URL, gravatar doesn't recognize the hashed email address, so it redirects to the fallback image that you provided: http://www.mysite.com/media/images/no-avatar.gif

- Is it correct that you get the fallback? Or did you expect a real gravatar? If so, the error is in the hash somehow.
- mysite.com is obviously not your site. But, did you in reality use the correct URL?
- A hardcoded URL: are you using the correct hostname? The correct `MEDIA_URL` from your `settings.py`?

Comment: i didnt setup a fallback image. I expected the gravatar to comeup

Comment: tried github.com/nvie/django-gravatar but it also loads fallback image - big blue G

Comment: You *did* set up a fallback image. That's the 'default' one in your image url. And that's the one that shows up if I put your image's url in my browser. (And the URL fails, so that explains why you see no gravatar image in your page). Suggestion: remove the 'default' from your url and you'll at least see gravatar's own default image. After that works, you can worry about the gravatar_id.

Answer (score 0):

Refs [the doc](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement), always lower and strip the email.
Also, use `'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'+hash` instead of the legacy format.
Then the code looks like

```
url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/%s?%s" % (
    hashlib.md5(email.strip().lower()).hexdigest(),  
    urllib.urlencode({'default': default, 'size': size}))
```

For you code, its highly probably that email hash does not match anything. I tried my avatar using the format in your code, it works well. [Has the email been registered?](https://en.gravatar.com/site/signup/)